# Expose AJAX application to Google

Tags: ajax, seo

I have one big web app that is basically one page where every content is created dynamically. It also has a forum, how do I expose the forum to Google or other search engines? Should I create a seperate view of the forum especially designed for search engines?

Answer (score 0):

Use meta tag in your html. This metadata can be used by search engines (keywords).

```
<meta name="description" content="xyz your web site name etc">
<meta name="keywords" content="xyz your web site name etc">
<meta name="author" content="xyz your web site name etc">
```